# oauthlib creating own oauthlib2 in python falcon

Tags: python-2.7, falconframework, flask-oauthlib

My database look like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import os
import time
import datetime
import sys
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice import ChoiceType
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.url import URLType
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    fullname = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)


class Client(Base):

    Grand_choice = [('authorization_code', 'Authorization code')]
    Response_choice = [('code', 'Authorization code')]
    __tablename__ = 'client'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(String(250), default=uuid.uuid4() ,unique=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    grant_type = Column(ChoiceType(Grand_choice))
    response_type = Column(ChoiceType(Response_choice))
    scopes = Column(String(260))
    default_scopes = Column(String(260))
    redirect_uri = Column(URLType)
    default_redirect_uri = Column(URLType)

class Bearer_Token(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Bearer_Token'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('client.id'))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    scopes = Column(String(250))
    access_token = Column(String(100),unique=True)
    refresh_token = Column(String(100),unique=True)
    expires_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)


class Authorization_Code(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Authorization_code'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('client.id'))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    scopes = Column(String(250))
    code = Column(String(100),unique=True)
    expires_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_oauth.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

and my validator look like this

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import RequestValidator
from modelsforoauth import User ,Client, Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_oauth.db', echo=True)

Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker()
DBSession.bind = engine
session = DBSession()
#session.query(Client.client_id).first()


class MyRequestValidator(RequestValidator):

    def validate_client_id(self, client_id, request):
        try:
            session.query(Client).filter_by(client_id=client_id).first()
            return True
        except Client.DoesNotExist:
            return False
```

I wannted to define endpoint for my api in falcon.

```
from My_validator import MyRequestValidator

from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationServer

validator = MyRequestValidator()
server = WebApplicationServer(validator)


class AuthorizationView(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._authorization_endpoint = server

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
```

When I look at the documentation in the following link [oauthlibserver](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/server.html)

this clearly says that 
uri, http_method, body, headers = extract_params(request)

How do i acheive this in falcon
also i wanted to check if my datamodels are correct as per the requirement in documentaion

I also dont understand what should be scope and uri_redirect

If i have to make some changes in models or code please experts let me know
form a newbee

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extract param function should look like this:

`def extract_params(request):
    # returns uri, http_method, body, headers 
    return request.uri, request.method, request.stream.read(), request.headers`

Comment: this does not help me

Comment: can you elaborate more on this